# package or namespace load failed when trying to load 'stats' package in R

Tags: r, git

I have been trying to work with a git repository and my R 3.6.3 keeps giving me error messages. I have tried reinstalling both R and the stats package, installing Rtools, copying the stats directory from the R folder in other clients but none of seem to be working. The stats package is still found among my packages but R keeps failing to load the .dll file.

The exact error I get is:

```
Error message: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...): unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll': LoadLibrary failure: The specified module could not be found. During startup - Warning message: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
```

Comment: Are you possibly trying to use the 3.6.3 stats package with R 4.0.0? The new R version requires reinstalling all packages but recommended packages such as stats are included in a standard R installation. Your description of what you did is therefore confusing and concerning. Also, how is git involved in an issue with your R installation?

Comment: @Roland I am using the stats package that comes with the version. The reason why I mentioned Git is because the stats package works fine when I am not using the repository I cloned from Github.

Comment: Does the repository contain your library folder? I still suspect you are using a package build for an older R version.

Comment: "Sharing your error message in a way that will be searchable" most likely means that you paste the error as text in your message, not as part of an image.

Comment: @Roland What library folder? I am using a repository created by  group of researchers.

Comment: Does this repository contain a build package? I'm pretty sure your issue is that you are trying to use a package build with an old R version with R 4.0.0. You'll have to investigate this further yourself since I don't know your repository. You'll probably need to get the package source and build the package with your R version.